Computing the trace of the product $\prod_{k = 1}^{2018}(kA + I_2)$
I have the matrix
$A = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -6\\1 & -2\end{pmatrix}$
and I want to compute the trace of the product
$$\prod_{k = 1}^{2018}(kA + I_2).$$
I am not sure what to do about this. I was thinking I could maybe use the fact that the matrix $A$ is idempotent (as it's easy to verify), but the only way I found this useful is if I could somehow expand the product into a nice form, which doesn't seem too doable. Something about it tells me the answer is related to eigenvalues (and I know the sum of the eigenvalues gives the trace itself), but this is from a textbook that assumes zero knowledge of such things as linear transformations or eigenvalues and eigenvectors, it just treats matrices as opaque algebraic objects, so I don't think a solution related to more advanced topics is intended, therefore I would appreciate if someone could provide an answer that doesn't rely on that. Is there a smart trick that should be applied?

This following method assumes no knowledge of eigenvalues and linear maps.
Let $p(x)=(1+x)(1+2x)\ldots(1+2018x)$. Our goal is to find $p(A)$.
Using remainder theorem, you have:
$$p(x)\equiv p(0)=1\pmod{x}\\ p(x)\equiv p(1)=2019!\pmod{x-1}$$
Solving this system of congruences (unique solution is guaranteed by Chinese Remainder theorem since $\gcd(x,x-1)=1$), you get $$p(x)\equiv (2019!-1)x+1\pmod{x\cdot(x-1)}$$
Thus, you can write $p(x)=(x^2-x)\,q(x)+(2019!-1)x+1\tag*{}$ for some $2016$-degree polynomial $q(x)$.
Now as you've verified, $A^2=A$, we have:
$\require{cancel}p(A)=\cancel{(A^2-A)\,q(A)}+(2019!-1)A+I_2\tag*{}$
Now finding $\text{trace}(p(A))$ is routine.
$$\begin{align}\text{trace}(p(A)) &= (2019!-1)\times \text{trace}(A)+\text{trace}(I_2)\\&=2019!+1.\quad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Of course, with some knowledge of linear algebra, one would observe that $A\sim \pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$. And it would follow that: (I'm skipping a few steps here.)
$$\begin{align}&\text{trace}\!\left(\prod_{k = 1}^{2018}(kA + I_2)\right) \\&= \text{trace}\!\left(\prod_{k = 1}^{2018}\left(k\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0} + \pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1}\right)\right)\\&=\text{trace}\!\left(\prod_{k = 1}^{2018}\pmatrix{k+1&0\\ 0&1}\right)\\&=\text{trace}\!\pmatrix{2019!&0\\ 0&1}\\&=2019!+1\end{align}$$
